# "Dramatisch pointiert"

Tags: meaning, translation, meaning-in-context

The meanings I found of "pointiert" do not seem to apply to the following sentence:

> "Eine Ballade ist ein Lied, das eine Geschichte erzählt, *die dramatisch pointiert ist*"

Does it mean "that is focused on drama"? "that is of dramatic nature / kind"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think *pointiert* means "zugespitzt" here. They want to say, that a ballad is a text with a dramatic culmination, i.e. the plot is dramatically organized, roughly meaning it has some antagonistic forces working against each other, and it reaches a climax at some point.

Just as a sidenote: Also be aware, that *Lied* in this context does not translate to "song", but rather to "poem".

Comment: Gibt es Situationen, in denen pointiert nicht zugespitzt bedeutet?